# Знаки препинания

Tags: пунктуация

При работе в утреннюю смену(,) сотрудник накануне(:) в период с 18 до 20 (,)связывается с администратором (,) для уточнения места и времени подачи автомобиля.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При работе в утреннюю смену сотрудник накануне, в период с 18 до 20, связывается с администратором для уточнения места и времени подачи автомобиля.

Пояснение: первый обстоятельственный оборот можно не обособлять в тексте делового стиля, обособляется только уточняющее обстоятельство.

Comment: Все так, но в русском русском языке скорее еще и "в период с 18 до 20 *часов*"